# Changing from router DHCP to Server DHCP

Tags: router, dhcp, vlan

I want to setup a Linux DHCP server instead of a router based DHCP. I'm guessing that I will need to turn off the router DHCP, but keep the router as the gateway. I think that the BCAST DHCP requests will reach my server on the local network computers. Does this make sense in theory will it work ?

I'm wondering how does this work with larger networks and VLANS ?

Comment: First learn how DHCP works, then concern yourself with VLANS :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The router has to be the gateway.  Otherwise you won't be able to get out of your LAN.  Create a new DHCP scope, but don't activate it.  When it comes time to put it in place, activate it and turn off DHCP from the router.  Just make sure your DHCP scope on the server points at the correct DNS servers and that it points to the router for the gateway.